# representing mandatory field in uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a tableview which has few textfield and popovers for data entry. I want to represent some of them as mandatory. I can could not figure out how to resent the asterisk. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use custom UITableViewCell. This will allow you to put almost anything you want into a cell.

Here is [where to start](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html). Also there are tons of examples on the SO and the web.